# Possible Bug in wordlistgenerator crunch in Kali Linux 2020.1?

Tags: kali-linux, password-generation, crunch

While trying out the wordlist generator `crunch` in Kali Linux I came across the following behaviour:

```
root@kali:/home/kali# crunch 10 10 \
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890,.-:! -o chars.txt
Crunch will now generate the following amount of data: 1604471776359824323 bytes
1530143524513 MB
1494280785 GB
1459258 TB
1425 PB
Crunch will now generate the following number of lines: 1822837804551761449

root@kali:/home/kali# crunch 10 10 \
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890,.-: -o chars.txt
Crunch will now generate the following amount of data: 17251705690018753536 bytes
16452508630770 MB
16066902959 GB
15690334 TB
15322 PB
Crunch will now generate the following number of lines: 1568336880910795776
```

How come removing the exclamation mark blows up the calculated wordlist size to 15322PB in contrast to being 1425PB if it were to be included?

For me this very much looks like a bug in the code.

Comment: Are you trying to output this to text? Lol either way it's not going to work. So your perceived bug doesn't really matter. You need to pipe it from memory for anything more than a couple terabytes... What happens when you call on the char sets abbreviated from the man page?

Comment: It's not that removing the exclamation point "blows up" the wordlist size, it's that _adding_ it **shrinks** the size. Adding any 68th character to the list of 67 you have in your second command line has the same effect. The list grows with each char added up to 67 (8199PB, 9622PB, 11264PB, 13153PB, 15322PB), then it drops to 1425PB and starts growing again as you extend the list. I'm pretty sure you're just hitting a storage limit in some variable somewhere, most likely 16KPB is the maxval. (I'm choosing to avoid the question of what possible use a 16KPB-long wordlist would be.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `-l` before the characters that you will be using, something like this:

```
crunch 10 10 -l abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890,.-:! -o chars.txt
```

`-l` in `crunch` means literal, and when specified `crunch` prints the `!` literally. This could also be used when you want to print `@` `,` or `%`.